# What if you 'placed' the Chicxulub asteroid onto the Earth?

Tags: asteroids, size, impact, modeling

We all know what sort of devastating impact an asteroid could have if it collided with the Earth.

But I'm curious to know what the effects would be if you removed the speed element from it, and were somehow able to casually 'place' a giant asteroid onto our planet?

I think I read somewhere that the Chicxulub asteroid was most likely around 9 miles long, and that the end of it would have extended beyond our atmosphere if it hit the Earth lengthways.

But would this have any effect if it was travelling at, say, 2mph? There would be nothing burning in the atmosphere or shockwaves etc.

Would it have any affect at all apart from squashing whatever was underneath?

If the answer is no... how about placing a moon-sized object onto the Earth?

Comment: Note:  To remove the speed would require magic.  The absolute minimum speed that an asteroid could have on hitting the atmosphere is almost 11km/s

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this requires magic.

Comment: @Pel Please consider editing your question: I guess you are asking what the effect of placing a huge object on the Earth's surface would make, do you? If so, I would write it that way, e.g. "What happens if we could bring a body of $80 {\rm km}$ diameter and a mass of $10^{16} {\rm kg}$ on Earth's surface?"

Comment: You could ask on Worldbuilding Meta if they would be willing to take a question about this. You'd probably have to substantially reword the question to define the parameters for which you'd like to see an answer and give context about why you want to know.

Comment: Shame it's been closed... I've seen (and asked) other ridiculous questions like this in the past and there's been no issues

Comment: @Pel ha! better not advertise that you've "asked other ridiculous questions", or someone may go back and vote to close them as well! I always feel bad if my questions are closed. It's not a perfect system but since this site is completely open to the internet there needs to be some limits. For this one, you could consider asking a question in Earth Science SE about placing a very large body on Earth and how it would compress the Earth below it, or about the atmospheric forces on it. At 2 MPH it would displace a lot of air and make wind, but not make a shock wave.

Comment: @Pel in Space SE there may be some questions about megastructures extending from the surface to space, I'm not sure. But you might have fun asking this type of question in [Worldbuilding SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @uhoh thanks! I didn't realise there was  an Earth Science SE actually... although I have to disagree with some of the others about my question requiring 'magic' – I'm sure in hundreds, or perhaps thousands of years we'd have the technology to do such things with asteroids (if we actually wanted to ha)

Comment: @uhoh ...here is one of my other equally strange / curious questions I was referring to if you'd like to take a look  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35101/how-long-could-an-ocean-last-in-space

Comment: @uhoh oh wow I've actually just noticed you commented on my other question back when I first posted it haha!

Comment: @Pel ya I wanted to let you and other readers know that the question wasn't so terribly unreasonable :-) Btw your comment about magic reminds me of the third of [Clarke's three laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An asteroid resting on Earth would be a mountain. Or, for smaller asteroids, a pile of gravel.

Mountains are limited in altitude by the strength of stone to resist compression: a too tall mountain would sink down as the base crumbled and spread out. [The limit on Earth is about 10 km](https://talkingphysics.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/how-high-can-mountains-be/). Besides the strength issue mountains are also floating ("[isostasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isostasy)") on the fluid but denser interior of Earth, so even if it doesn't fall apart it may sink down partially.

So the impactor would not hold together that well. A big ball of rock 10 km in diameter would first definitely sink down several kilometres into the crust, and almost definitely break. That means that something like $10^{15}$ kg will descend several kilometres, giving an energy $mgh \approx 10^{19}$ J (and there are estimates 100 times larger for the mass). That is "just" like a big hurricane, but will mostly be released as localized seismic energy and heating. The end result would be a massive pile that likely destabilizes the crust in the vicinity a lot: far less than an actual high velocity impact, but still a major disaster.

If you do the same with the moon you will break up the crust, boil off the oceans and wipe out all life on the planet.

Comment: Lol wow - sounds interesting! Thanks for satisfying my curiosity